# Pickling instances of a class whose instances are classes

Tags: python, class, types, instance, pickle

I have a class whose instances are classes. Each instance has its own name. I can add that name to the enclosing module when the new class is created, which allows me to pickle.dump it. Originally, I didn't add the name to the module, but I had a **reduce** method in the top-level class. Unfortunately, there's some mysterious code in the pickle module that special-cases subclasses of type and looks for the name in the module rather than calling reduce. If that code were inside a try, and just continued to the **reduce** code on failure, I think using reduce would work fine.

Anyway, the problem with just adding the name is that on pickle.load, the name doesn't exist and the load fails. Presumably, I could add a **getattr** to the module to interpret the name and create the corresponding class, but my understanding is that not all versions of python support module-level **getattr**.

The **reduce** method in the class instances allows successfully pickling instances of those class instances by recreating the class instances on pickle.load, but pickling the class instances themselves doesn't work.

Other than making a slightly nonstandard pickle module, is there some reasonable solution to allow pickling of the class instances?

Comment: I suspect this is something that pickle will not be able to do, but that [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) should manage.

Comment: dill has the exact same problem. My suggestion would be to call __reduce__ (or __reduce_x__) if present before doing anything special based on the type.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Would you mind posting the code defining your metaclass and classes aswell as the reason they are not defined yet on pickle.load?

Comment: The code is here: https://github.com/ms0/pymath/blob/master/ffield.py
I'm not familiar with pickle.load, other than the method of that name.